# F# game development: Modifying state variables

Tags: c#, .net, f#

```
open SFML.Graphics
open SFML.Window

let window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(200u, 200u), "SFML works!")
let shape = new CircleShape(10.0f, FillColor=Color.Green)
let mutable pressedKey = Keyboard.Key.Unknown

let moveKeys = [ Keyboard.Key.Up; Keyboard.Key.Left;
                 Keyboard.Key.Down; Keyboard.Key.Right ]

let keyPress (e : KeyEventArgs) =
    match e.Code with
    | moveKeys -> pressedKey <- e.Code
    | _ -> pressedKey <- Keyboard.Key.Unknown

let keyRelease (e : KeyEventArgs) =
    let pressedKeys = List.filter (fun key -> Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(key)) moveKeys
    if pressedKeys.IsEmpty then pressedKey <- Keyboard.Key.Unknown
    else pressedKey <- pressedKeys.Head

window.Closed.Add(fun evArgs -> window.Close())
window.KeyPressed.Add(keyPress)
window.KeyReleased.Add(keyRelease)

while window.IsOpen() do
    match pressedKey with
    | Keyboard.Key.Up    -> shape.Position <- new Vector2f(shape.Position.X, shape.Position.Y - 0.1f)
    | Keyboard.Key.Left  -> shape.Position <- new Vector2f(shape.Position.X - 0.1f, shape.Position.Y)
    | Keyboard.Key.Down  -> shape.Position <- new Vector2f(shape.Position.X, shape.Position.Y + 0.1f)
    | Keyboard.Key.Right -> shape.Position <- new Vector2f(shape.Position.X + 0.1f, shape.Position.Y)
    | _ -> ()

    window.DispatchEvents()
    window.Clear()
    window.Draw(shape)
    window.Display()
```

In the above code sample I create a circle and let it move around by pressing arrow keys. The state variable in question is the position of the circle, represented by a Vector2f object (part of the SFML library)

My question relates to the end of the code segment, where I find the pressed key and then move the circle. From a C# background this part of my code seems bad.

In C# I would simply do the following:

```
switch (pressedKey) {
    case Keyboard.Key.Up:
         shape.Position.Y -= 0.1f;
    // etc, etc
}
```

1. Does creating these new Vector2f objects cause unnecessary
   overhead compared to the way I would modify the state variable in
   C#?
2. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) This is a performance question which is always case specific.  The answer in this case is No.  If you are doing this to 10,000 objects in a loop then yes, use mutable data.  In general making things immutable allows you to make easier assumptions about their behavior which is hugely important.

2) Here is a possible direction you can go with this code.

```
open SFML.Graphics
open SFML.Window
open System

type HandleKeyboard(window : RenderWindow) =
    let mutable keyState = Set.empty

    let keyPressedHandle = 
        window.KeyPressed.Subscribe(fun key -> 
            keyState <- keyState.Add key.Code)

    let keyReleasedHandle = 
        window.KeyReleased.Subscribe(fun key -> 
            keyState <- keyState.Remove key.Code)

    let validMovementKey (keyPress : Keyboard.Key) =
        match keyPress with
        | Keyboard.Key.Up
        | Keyboard.Key.Left
        | Keyboard.Key.Down
        | Keyboard.Key.Right -> true
        | _ -> false

    let keyToMovement (keyPress : Keyboard.Key) =
        match keyPress with
        | Keyboard.Key.Up    -> Vector2f( 0.0f, -0.1f)
        | Keyboard.Key.Left  -> Vector2f(-0.1f,  0.0f)
        | Keyboard.Key.Down  -> Vector2f( 0.0f,  0.1f)
        | Keyboard.Key.Right -> Vector2f( 0.1f,  0.0f)
        | _ -> Vector2f(0.0f, 0.0f)

    member this.IsKeyPressed (key : Keyboard.Key) = 
        keyState |> Set.contains key

    member this.GetMovement () =
        keyState
        |> Set.filter validMovementKey
        |> Seq.map keyToMovement
        |> Seq.fold (+) (Vector2f(0.0f, 0.0f))

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() =
            keyPressedHandle.Dispose()
            keyReleasedHandle.Dispose()

type SomeState = { 
    position : Vector2f;
    }

let startGame() =
    use window = new RenderWindow(VideoMode(200u, 200u), "SFML works!")
    use shape = new CircleShape(10.0f, FillColor = Color.Green)
    use keyboard = new HandleKeyboard(window)

    window.Closed.Add(fun evArgs -> window.Close())

    let rec mainLoop state =
        window.DispatchEvents()

        if keyboard.IsKeyPressed Keyboard.Key.Escape then
            window.Close()

        let newPosition = state.position + keyboard.GetMovement()
        shape.Position <- newPosition

        if window.IsOpen() then
            window.Clear()
            window.Draw(shape)
            window.Display()

            mainLoop {position = newPosition}

    mainLoop {position = Vector2f(0.0f, 0.0f)}

startGame()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you are worried about the overhead of creating a small object corresponding to a keypress, you are worrying about the wrong thing.  The number of keypresses is relatively small.

By changing your vector2 type, you can make it possible to write code similar to the C# code ( essentially, you make the backing store variables mutable).

Comment: My point is that I am creating a new object every frame in that while loop (an updated position for the circle). If I was handling thousands or more objects in this way and creating new objects every frame as opposed to modifying mutable fields within the object would there be a noticeable performance difference? Are mutable fields preferable?